# I need to do math from ground up, so what is a good workbook?

Tags: reference-request, education

Can you guys recommend me a workbook that begins with arithmetic and ends with calculus.
Or from pre-algebra to calculus.
Like all "Master Math Series" books but in one complete book.

It would really help me if you knew a few.

Thanks.

Comment: I find it hard to believe there is one (that gives arithmetic more than a few pages of treatment). I'm not sure why you couldn't just get a precalculus text and a calculus text.

Comment: Take a set of text books on the subjects you wish to cover, tear off the backs of all the covers except for the last and the fronts of all the covers except for the first, use Elmer's wood glue and put it together like a book.

Comment: You could try Khan Academy.

Comment: I'm not in a position to answer the OP, but for others out there, I think that the OP wants a "complete narrative" so to speak. Not necessarily a literal single book, but at the least a series of books that build on each other. In my experience, one thing that math students always find confusing is when different math books talk about related topics but with slightly different interpretations, or worse, slightly different notation. I for one would like to see if such a series of texts exists that ties everything together nicely.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i meant.

Thanks for making it easier for me to interpret my question.

Answer (score -1):

Technically these are many books, but check out the Easy Way series. It has algebra, geometry, trig, pre-calculus, and calculus, (maybe some other books that I did not know before) with plenty of practice problems. There are also other books in this series if you are interested.

Comment: Why the downvote?